# Performance benefits of using max() over manual loop for finding maximum

Tags: python, list

As a beginner in Python, I'm currently delving into the nuances of efficient coding practices. My journey has led me to explore the differences in performance between using Python's built-in `max()` function and implementing a manual loop to find the largest value within a dictionary or list. The focus of my inquiry is on understanding the practical benefits, if any, of opting for the built-in function over a manually coded loop, especially in terms of runtime efficiency and code readability.

For context, I've conducted a small experiment using a dictionary derived from a project I'm working on. My goal is to apply Just-In-Time (JIT) learning techniques while honing my Python skills. The experiment involved timing the execution of both methods (using `max()` and a manual for-loop) to compare their performance.

Here's a simplified version of the code snippets used for testing:

```
import time

dict = {}
highest_bid = 0

dict = { 'alpha' : 1, 'bravo':2, 'charlie' : 3, 'delta':4,'echo':5, 'foxtrot':6, 'golf':7, 'hotel':8, 'india':9, 'juliet':10, 'kilo':11, 'lima':12, 'mike':13, 'november':14, 'oscar':15, 'papa':16, 'quebec':17}

# Timer to compare bid max process time
start = time.process_time()

# for finding the max value, iterable method
for temp in dict:
  if int(dict[temp]) > highest_bid:
    highest_bid = dict[temp]
    highest_bidder = temp

# VERSUES : 
# for finding the max value, max() method
highest_bid = max(dict.values())
highest_bidder = max(dict, key=dict.get)

# Computed timing
print(time.process_time() - start)
print(f"{highest_bidder} and ${highest_bid}")
```

Surprisingly, the results from my tests were inconclusive, with minimal differences in runtime between the two approaches. This outcome has left me pondering the advantages of using `max()` over a manual for-loop, beyond what my basic test has revealed.

**Could anyone provide insights into:**

- The underlying efficiency of `max()` compared to a manual loop, especially in larger datasets or more complex scenarios?
- Situations where one method might significantly outperform the other?
- Any considerations regarding code maintainability and readability when choosing between these two approaches?

I'm eager to understand the deeper implications of choosing built-in functions over manual implementations, particularly from the perspective of experienced Python developers.

*Time is the same using the replit, with runtime results ranging from (*10^{-5]): 1-5 .*

Comment: finding the maximum in a sequence has linear runtime. No way around it and little room to optimize this. You keep mentioning the main arguments yourself all the time: Readability, maintainability. Why would you write a loop yourself that a) has the chance of you making a minor typo causing issues b) takes a little bit more time for someone else to understand. This is an opinion, but the beauty of Python (to me) is the high degree of readability for statements like `highest_bid = max(dict.values())`

Comment: `max` has to retrieve and compare the items to process in the same way as a manual loop, there isn't much room for optimization. Generally, premature optimization should be avoided. Create clean, working code, measure it with a profiler and optimize the bottlenecks based on the profiler results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post my results when it comes to finding the max, I defined a range `L`, a list created by `list(range(n))`. This can be checked with the fucntion `manualMax` here:

```
def manualMax(L):
    highest_bid = 0
    for val in L:
        if val > highest_bid:
            highest_bid = val
    return highest_bid
```

Or with the regular Python `max()` function.

I would like to mention, that when you want to test such things, you need to increase your sample size `n`. Since small values of `n` will not show the true benefit of using one function over the other. For this, check the following definition of the big O notation:

[*Big O notation is a mathematical notation that describes the limiting behavior of a function when the argument tends towards a particular value or infinity.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

Using the following snippets:

```
n = 1000000
L = list(range(n))
def manualMax(L):
    highest_bid = 0
    for val in L:
        if val > highest_bid:
            highest_bid = val
    return highest_bid
%timeit manualMax(L)
%timeit max(L)
```

The results for `manualMax`:

```
20.2 ms ± 1.67 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

And for `max()`:

```
11.8 ms ± 847 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

As you can see, the built-in function is almost twice as fast. But why? Don't the functions *basically* do the same thing?

The short answer is that they do, but the built-in one is optimized, while the self-written one in Python is not. The long is that built-in functions are implemented in C, a lower-level language than Python.

Comment: `max` being implemented in C accounts for about half of the observed speed-up. The other half comes from `list_iterator`, the kind of object both functions iterate over, *also* being implemented in C.

Comment: @chepner That argument doesn't make sense. If something is used by both solutions, how does it contribute to a speed-up of one of them?

Comment: @Tino What Python version did you use?

Comment: And what times do you get with`L = list(range(n)[::-1])`?

Comment: I implemented a pure-Python iterator, and the difference between `max` and `manualMax` was less pronounced.

Comment: @chepner Ah, ok. I just wouldn't call that a speed-up but say that it makes the actual speed-up more visible/significant.

Comment: @chepner Or ... wait ... does "less pronounced" mean the absolute time difference was larger?

Comment: @KellyBundy With a built-in list, it was 14.3 ms vs 35.4 ms. With a class implementing `__iter__` as a generator function, it was 65.5 ms vs 89.8 ms.

Comment: @chepner Ok, I'd rather call that the opposite then, 21.1 ms speedup with the C iterator and a *larger* 24.3 ms speedup with the Python iterator.

Comment: @KellyBundy python version 3.11.5

Comment: @chepner I did not understand if I did something wrong or if I might have misrepresented the benefits of using one approach over the other. Can you please post your findings as an answer for everyone? Percentage-wise, I see that the speed-up is less, even though, as Kelly Bundy mentioned, the absolute speed-up in ms is higher for `__iter__`

Comment: Actually, the results are worse if `__iter__` is *really* implemented in Python (see my answer). The iterator I alluded to earlier was actually a generator function, which still produces a `generator` object implemented in C.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR Things written in C tend to be faster than pure Python equivalents because they bypass the overhead of the interpreter, but any implementation of `max` has to contend with the speed of the iterator it uses as well, and this can dominate the time it spends actually comparing values retrieved from the iterator.

---

There are two components here: the implementation of `max`, and the implementation of the iterator. Lists themselves are not iterators: calling `iter(L)` returns not the list itself, but an wrapper of type `list_iterator` which provides a `__next__` method to retrieve items from the list. Just as `list` is a built-in type, so is `list_iterator`.

Here's are a pair of classes that implement a `range`-like iterator in pure Python:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n

    def __iter__(self):
        return FooIter(self.n)

class FooIter:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.x = 0
        self.n = n
    def __next__(self):
        if self.x >= self.n:
            raise StopIteration

        rv = self.x
        self.x += 1
        return rv
```

Using the same test setup from https://stackoverflow.com/a/78005880/1126841, you see that `max` is significantly faster than `manualMax` for a built-in `list` object.

```
n = 1000000
L1 = list(range(n))
L2 = Foo(n)
def manualMax(L):
    highest_bid = 0
    for val in L:
        if val > highest_bid:
            highest_bid = val
    return highest_bid

In [1]: %timeit max(L1)
14.3 ms ± 192 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [2]: %timeit manualMax(L1)
36.4 ms ± 1.25 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

For an instance of `Foo`, though, it is only slightly faster.

```
In [3]: %timeit max(L2)
222 ms ± 2.48 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [4]: %timeit manualMax(L2)
249 ms ± 5.57 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Wouldn't you say that the majority of that time is exhausted while iterating the `list_iterator`? It seems to me that 210 ms were added uniformly to both approaches.

Comment: Yes, that's the point. The built-in `max` is faster than `manualMax` because it is implement in C, not pure Python, but both implementations are strongly affected by the performance of the thing they iterate over. If you iterator is slow, it matters less and less how fast your implementation of `max` is, especially as the size of the iterable increases.

Comment: Nicely put. This is the longer *long* version of my answer

Comment: Here's a puzzle: Why is my Python implementation ~10% *faster* than the C built-in? Link will be in the next comment, click on "Execute" there and see the times appear below. I get ~17.5 ms for `mymax` and ~19.5 ms for `max`. Also @TinoD

Comment: https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZJNTsMwEIUllnOK2TWuQiCUIhQpnIF9iaKU2GCBnch2q1ZVT8GSTTew5wocg9Ngj9Mf2CSZb8Yz7038_tmv3XOnd7uPhRPntz9nb8J0Cp1UHKXqO-PoG4iaRrf-NfAYAbRcoFqrZpWsLCsAUTos_YObAHwsOoM-jVJ7Ggoi-gP8KeHJXSjcE6RTJa4oNtwtjA4IQCz0o_UZH6RxNsAqgFkUlTCaUIcJnjzxJL8cj29YBXCw51WeGJQuZqxrnLRO-vZDVvFGp563fAkDsmsLEE6FkRtR4KyieSLMI21b2kpoZhPBoiFHAh2OMecTqneh3vqOvE2o3UxUbFZMq-rUsRjhJohInF_vdZaLLX5_4YYUEZsQUxZH8M_11ZQd931Ud1xw-FPRfvLaqHnbFCjCX0tRL9ScmzJneIH5sX5QmTV9z7VXzeDQejBCE1J84euS_A8KeiO1S_YbSVFkda0bxeuaAcTk6EHf020sRmnYcbbkxspOs3g3hyu6v6q_

Comment: @KellyBundy witchcraft?