# Time Complexity of "in" keyword in python when using a list? Leetcode

Tags: python, time-complexity, space-complexity, code-complexity

I read a little bit everywhere that the "in" operator have a time complexity of O(n), yet I used it in a code and idk why but it's acting as if it have the time complexity O(1)

So I was solving a problem on leetcode and ended up having this algorithm

```
class Solution(object):
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        i=0
        n=len(nums)
        for i in range (0, n-1):
            if (target-nums[i]) in nums:
                for j in range (i+1, n):
                    if nums[i]+nums[j]==target:
                        return[i, j]
```

[image: No.1]
and I ended up having runtime pretty similar to code like these that involve hashmaps:

```
class Solution(object):
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        hash_map = {}

        for i in range(len(nums)):
            complement = target - nums[i]
            if complement in hash_map.keys():
                return [i, hash_map[complement]]
            hash_map[nums[i]] = i
```

[image: No.2]
It's weird because I read everywhere that the time complexity of the in operator for list is O(n), so I assumed this line

`if (target-nums[i]) in nums:`

would make my code equivalent to

```
class Solution(object):
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        self=list()
        n=len(nums)
        for i in range(n-1):
          for j in range(i+1,n):
            if nums[i]+nums[j]==target:
              return [i,j]
```

[image: No.3]

yet it has the runtime of a code using hashmaps, and uses the memory of the code using the same list so O(1), anyone could explain that to me please?
To recap shouldn't solution1 have a runtime closer or exactly as solution3? Yet it's closer to solution2.

No1 No2 and No3 have screenshots of runtime and memory of each code.

Comment: How do you measured consumed time?

Comment: @Daweo in leetcode they show you the runtime of the solution you provide, and you can even compare it to solutions with similar runtimes.

Comment: Time complexity is not about the time it takes to run different algorithms on the same data, it's about how the time taken by a specific algorithm evolves depending on the size of the data. On small data, some O(n^3) could well be faster than a more evolved O(n) algorithm, but will finally get slower when the data is "large enough".

Comment: This question seems to be more about the inner workings of leetcode than the code itself.

Comment: Why don't you profile the code yourself using? Also, O notation is behaviour as size tends to infinity -> make sure you are testing with big lista. See my answer here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78005880/16815358

Comment: Thanks @TinoD your answer was the most logical ! Also as they use a huge set of test cases, I'm sure it's enough to see the difference of O notation.

Comment: You should really tell the times you got from LeetCode, and a good test case with times you measured yourself. The second solution is just utterly stupid, and showing the test case and times would make that more obvious so you wouldn't be dismissed so easily.

Comment: Alright I edited the post and added runtime
Also I'm sorry I'm not sure if I understood correctly but why would the hashmap solution be utterly stupid? 
Leetcode doesn't show the testcases other than the 3 first examples that are pretty simple so I wouldn't be able to tell ya

Comment: `in range(...)` isn't actually a list search at all. `range()` creates a range object, not a list, and checking whether something is in a range _is_ an O(1) operation. That aspect of the question is duplicative of [python 3 range vs python 2 range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44571718/python-3-range-vs-python-2-range)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm not talking about in range
I'm talking about the "in" used in this line: if (target-nums[i]) in nums:

Comment: Your _docs_ say that `nums` is a list, but do we know that's really true? If it were a range, that would explain observed behavior perfectly. Remember that `List` is more general than `list` -- something can be a `List` while only being `list`-_like_.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `range(...)` does create a list.

Comment: @KellyBundy, ...not since Python 2. Read the linked question on the topic above.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Exactly!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy "Do we know that's really true?":
Input: nums = [2,7,11,15], target = 9
Output: [0,1]
Explanation: Because nums[0] + nums[1] == 9, we return [0, 1].
Here's one of the 3 examples shown in the problem, all inputs are syntaxed or should be syntaxed that way.

Comment: @Erray, fair, but we need to know the types passed for the _really big_ examples used to calculate big-O, not the types passed for the tiny sample examples. If leetcode were using a range for the huge examples -- well, that would be a good choice from a memory-efficiency perspective, so I could understand why someone on their implementation team might be tempted.

Comment: @Erray, ...if you want an example that can actually be tested concretely, you need to build one that doesn't depend on leetcode. Something that uses the timeit module and generates a large _list_ of data in the (untimed) `setup()` section, f/e.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Did you get the hints, or should I just say it?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'll try doing that, ty.

Comment: Coming up with an exemplar for OP would have been much more productive than the long discussion...

Comment: @Dmitry It's not just "list-like", it **is** a list.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks everyone, I was a bit lost (I'm still a beginner)
I appreciate it!

Comment: @ThierryLathuille What's the typo?

Answer (score 2):

You chose to use Python 2, so `if complement in hash_map.keys():` creates a list of keys and searches in that list. Instead of doing the fast lookup in the hashmap. Entirely negating why it was used in the first place. That's why the hashmap solution isn't much faster. Remove the `.keys()`. Or choose Python 3, which you should anyway. Python 2 is dead.